# How to change text color of the last two menus

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering how to change the color of the last two menus, what I want is instead of using black for the last two menus I want to use white.

URL: https://hrcstaging.wpengine.com/

[image]

the last two menus is designed like a button and I want to change the text color to white.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an ID to those elements and add a CSS property to them.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="white-link" href="#">Verify Insurance</a>
<a id="white-link" href="#">Number</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a#white-link {
    color: white;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w0jkq2e6/)

Answer (score 0):

with css you can use

```
button{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Or the buttons class, in this case it would be

```
.btnClass{
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css to your css file.

```
.main-navigation .main-nav ul li:nth-last-child(2) a,.main-navigation .main-nav ul li:last-child a{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Oops, If I add this code the sub menus will became white also

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add two classes with the same name to your buttons. Do

```css
.white{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class='white'>Verify Insurance</button>
<button class='white'>(704)-970-4106</button>
```

Mention that the button tag can be whatever html element with custom properties. It can be an a tag for example.

You can also replace the #fff code by the name of the color as #fff is the white hex code.

Comment: I tried to put a class but its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
li#menu-item-4779 a, li#menu-item-4780 a  {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

thanks guys I got the code and it works good now

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more dynamic approach than using IDs, and your menu will retain the same number of list items, you can use pseudo classes. `:nth-child` should work. `:nth-of-type` might also work, but I'd use `:nth-child`.

```css
#menu-primary-menu li:nth-child(7) a, #menu-primary-menu li:nth-child(8) a { color: white }
```

or

```css
#menu-primary-menu li:nth-of-type(7) a, #menu-primary-menu li:nth-of-type(8) a { color: white }
```

In your case, if the IDs won't ever change, that's the easiest way, but it's good to know about pseudo classes in general.

Answer (score 0):

ok, for te last item menu:

```
.your_custom_menu ul li:last-child a{ /** your code here  */ }
```

for the item before the last:

```
.your_custom_menu ul li:last-child(2) a{ /** your code here  */ }
```